onPopInvokedWithResult being called twice
I have a PopScope that handles some cleanup, but for some reason, the onPopInvokedWithResult callback is being called twice.
How can this happen?
@immutable
class MyRoute extends GoRouteData {

  const MyRoute({
    // ...
  });

  @override
  Page buildPage(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) => MaterialPage(
        key: state.pageKey,
        child: PopScope(
          child: MyPageWithScaffold(
            // ...
          ),
          onPopInvokedWithResult: (didPop, result) {
            if (didPop) {
              doCleanup();
            }
          },
        ),
      );
}

Update

I am not using a custom back button
As far as I can tell, there is no duplicate pop() call

From debugging, the first call comes from Navigator.maybePop(), and the next comes from Navigator.didUpdateWidget(). I would be interested in finding out if I can avoid this.
As a temporary workaround, I've added handling to avoid calling logic twice, which must only be called once.
